# Is this question "OK" even though it was a test just because it had a ton of comments and answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, review-audits

I was in the Triage review queue and came across this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15050022

I read through it and immediately felt like this request should be edited or closed.  It doesn't present any indication that the user created any code that want help with.  In my opinion it falls under Too Broad, or Should Be Closed... and I almost flagged it until I clicked on the question and saw that there were already hundreds of comments and many answers and that is was 22 days old (at the time I'm writing this).

I figured - "Ok, I guess this question is fine, it's got 14 upvotes and people are clearly providing answers to it" so I clicked "Looks OK" and then got the "Congratulations!  Test passed!"  message stating that they were just checking to make sure I was paying attention.

This didn't sit well with me.  If I had been one of the first reviewers, I would have voted to edit the post or close it as I mentioned above.  So my question is:  Is this question now suddenly acceptable simply because of the level of responses it has received when the question itself doesn't actually meet the guidelines for a quality question and should have been edited or removed?

Comment: Just my two cents, but I would say that question's fine. We have a lot of rules about what makes a "good" question, but I think that there's a certain degree of Stewartian, "I know it when I see it", judgement involved.   This question is clearly well thought out and informed and, more importantly, the asker has provided all the relevant information that one would need to provide an informed and helpful answer.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I guess that's what led me to select "Looks OK" ultimately.  But if I hadn't taken the time to look at the question, I probably would have voted otherwise.

Comment: Just so you know, not all good questions have to be about code. This is *programming* Q&A site, not a "debug my code for me" site.

Comment: @CodyGray that's fair, but I stand by my initial reaction.  The question is:  `I'm looking for alternative algorithms that would solve this faster than the naive O(N2) algorithm without FFT (nor NTT). Are there any simple and elegant solutions to this problem?` which would likely belong on the Math SE.  The comments and the answers eventually changed the "tone" of the question to one about programming.  If he had provided examples of what he had done and then said "Is there a better way to do this?" I would then suggest the CodeReview SE.  Either way I would have recommended editing the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not acceptable for a question to be Too Broad or merit closure for another reason and remain open because it has a lot of responses or other positive feedback.  Positive responses would be good reasons to *not delete* it (or at least be very hesitant of deletion), but it would still merit closure.

Those responses simply tricked the audit system; it assumes that because of the feedback given to the post, it must have been a good post.  This assumption is a reasonable approximation, but is not entirely accurate; every now and then a bad post gets positive feedback despite its problems; the audit system has no real way to deal with this.  It's also possible that you simply disagreed with others looking at the post (although the feedback needed to make a post an audit makes this a rare case).

Comment: Will voting to close it "Unsalvageable" actually do anything in those tests?

Comment: @akousmata yes.  It will fail the audit.  It won't affect the status of that question as an audit.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "fail the audit".  Will I as the user fail the audit or will the question?

Comment: @akousmata You, as a user, will fail the audit, if you say it should be closed and the audit thinks it's good.

Comment: Further reading on MSE: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)